# Having trouble killing some mutations

Tags: java, junit5, mutation-testing, pitest

I having some trouble killing some mutations and I don't understand why.

Here is the class that I'm testing

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class TasksDeclaration {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TasksDeclaration.class);

  private final ErrorLogFactory errorLogFactory;
  private final AccountConnectorClient accountConnectorClient;
  private final PublisherClient publisherClient;

  @Scheduled(cron = "${task.health-check.cron}")
  public void verifyServicesAreRunning() {
    DomainServiceStatus domainServiceStatus = DomainServiceStatus.INSTANCE;

    try {
      LOGGER.info("Verifying health status of - starting");

      domainServiceStatus.setAccountConnectorUp(isAccountConnectorRunning());
      domainServiceStatus.setPublisherUp(isPublisherRunning());

      LOGGER.info("Verifying health status - done - services are running");
    } catch (RetryableException ex) {
      domainServiceStatus.setAccountConnectorUp(false);
      domainServiceStatus.setPublisherUp(false);
    }
  }

  private boolean isAccountConnectorRunning() {
    ResponseEntity<HealthStatus> response = accountConnectorClient.HeathCheck();

    return (response.getBody().getStatus().equals(SERVICE_UP));
  }

  private boolean isPublisherRunning() {
    ResponseEntity<HealthStatus> response = publisherClient.HeathCheck();

    return (response.getBody().getStatus().equals(SERVICE_UP));
  }

}
```

Here is my test method

```
@Test
void verifyServicesAreRunning_error() throws FeignException {
  when(accountConnectorClient.HeathCheck()).thenThrow(new RetryableException(500, "message", Request.HttpMethod.GET, new Date(), DataFixture.getRequest()));

  tasksDeclaration.verifyServicesAreRunning();

  verify(accountConnectorClient).HeathCheck();

  assertFalse(DomainServiceStatus.INSTANCE.isAccountConnectorUp());
  assertFalse(DomainServiceStatus.INSTANCE.isPublisherUp());
}
```

The Pit Test Coverage Report is telling me that the 2 lines in my catch statement have survived despite the call being removed. What am I missing/not testing?

Comment: my recommendation is to manually apply the mutation and debug the test: if you remove the 2 lines in the catch clause, will your test pass? maybe it will because the 2 member fields are already false?

Comment: Are you sure that you are working on the same instance of `accountConnectorClient`? Is the value injected into `TasksDeclaration`?